# How do I use Django cluster or loading balance. Django + NGINX + uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx

I deployed the environment of Django + NGINX + uWSGI successfully. I wish I can run multi-Django server with one NGINX.
The configuration below is NGINX's conf:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}
```

Does it work just use IP: port? e.g.

```
upstream django {
    #server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 192.168.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    server 192.168.0.2:8002;
    server 192.168.0.1:8004;
    server 192.168.0.2:8004;
}
```

I want to use Unix sockets instead of ports. Because the mysite.sock files maybe in many different remote hosts. How do I configure NGINX's conf?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could run UNIX sockets behind a TCP connection using `socat`, but I don't recommend that complexity.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html#clustering

Change uwsgi to run as a TCP socket and adjust nginx to balance those TCP connections.